# album art not showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

**i m  new to android. in my music app i  m trying to show album art but its not displaying it.i dont know what is the issue with this. please give me some idea how to do it. cant find on internet.**

```
public class BlankFragment2 extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<songInfo> _songs = new ArrayList<songInfo>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    public songAdapter songAdapter1;
    ImageView album_art;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    byte[] art;

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private BlankFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public BlankFragment2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static BlankFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment2, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView. findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        songAdapter1 = new songAdapter(getActivity(),_songs);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(songAdapter1);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),
                linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
        songAdapter1.setOnItemClickListener(new songAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, View view, final songInfo obj, int position) {

                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    mediaPlayer = null;

                }else {

                    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(obj.getSongUrl());
                                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                        mp.start();
                                        seekBar.setProgress(0);
                                        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                                        Log.d("Prog", "run: " + mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                                    }
                                });

                            }catch (Exception e){}
                        }

                    };
                    myHandler.postDelayed(runnable,100);

                }
            }
        });
        checkUserPermission();

        Thread t = new runThread();
        t.start();
        return rootView;
    }

    public class runThread extends Thread {


        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("Runwa", "run: " + 1);
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    seekBar.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                        }
                    });

                    Log.d("Runwa", "run: " + mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void checkUserPermission(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=23){
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},123);
                return;
            }
        }
        loadSongs();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case 123:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    loadSongs();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    checkUserPermission();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        }

    }

    private void loadSongs() {
        MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0";
        Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selection, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                    String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));



                    try {
                        String pathId = cursor.getString(Integer.parseInt(url));
                        metaRetriver.setDataSource(pathId);
                        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "path id=" + pathId);
                        art = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
                        BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        opt.inSampleSize = 2;
                        Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length, opt);
                        album_art.setImageBitmap(songImage);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                       // album_art.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                        songInfo s = new songInfo(name, artist, url);
                        _songs.add(s);

                    }
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
                cursor.close();
                songAdapter1 = new songAdapter(getActivity(), _songs);
            }
        }

    }
    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (BlankFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
adapter
public  class songAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<songAdapter.SongHolder> {

    private ArrayList<songInfo> _songs = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;

    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

    public songAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<songInfo> songs) {
        this.context = context;
        this._songs = songs;
    }


    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, View view, songInfo obj, int position);

        // void onItemClick(Button b, View view, songInfo obj, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mOnItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }


    @Override
    public SongHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View myView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card,viewGroup,false);
        return new SongHolder(myView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SongHolder songHolder, final int i) {

        final songInfo s = _songs.get(i);
        songHolder.tvSongName.setText(_songs.get(i).getSongName());
        songHolder.tvSongArtist.setText(_songs.get(i).getArtistName());
        setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, View view, songInfo obj, int position) {
                if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                    mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(songHolder, view, s, i);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return _songs.size();
    }

    public class SongHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvSongName,tvSongArtist;
        ImageView album_art;
        public SongHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvSongName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.songName);
            tvSongArtist = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.artistName);
            album_art = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.albumArt);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my logs.

> No adapter attached; skipping layout 01-11 00:30:16.000
>   8631-8665/com.example.murarilal.atry D/Runwa: run: 1 01-11
>   00:30:16.002 8631-8631/com.example.murarilal.atry I/Choreographer:
>   Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its
>   main thread. 01-11 00:30:16.030 8631-8664/com.example.murarilal.atry
>   D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new instance of your adapter after you load songs which it's not bind to your `recyclerView`

so instead of creating new instance

```
songAdapter1 = new songAdapter(getActivity(), _songs);
```

call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of your adapter like below:

```
songAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

or you can simply remove `songAdapter1` field and do your job by calling

```
recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: so please update your question by adding your adapter code